# Atualizar variável do app-component Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um menu no app-component e preciso atualizar a variável IsLogged após o login do usuário para que o menu aparece correto após o login com sucesso.

```
<ion-item routerLink="home" *ngIf="!IsLogged">
    <ion-icon slot="start" name="log-in-outline"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>{{'sidemenu.signin' | transloco}}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
            
 <ion-item  (click)="DoLogOut()" *ngIf="IsLogged"> 
      <ion-icon slot="start" name="log-out-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>{{'sidemenu.signout' | transloco}}</ion-label>
 </ion-item>

 <ion-item  routerLink="dashboard" *ngIf="IsLogged">
      <ion-icon slot="start" name="apps-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>{{'sidemenu.app' | transloco}}</ion-label>
 </ion-item>
```

Criei um observable onde retorna o valor IsLogged como true, porém após o login a variável no app-component não é atualizado automaticamente, algum método para fazer esta atualização, por exemplo o component ficar "escutando" mudanças na variável?

```
this._LoginService.Session().subscribe(data => { this.IsLogged = data.IsLOgged }).unsubscribe;
```

Comment: É só vc dar um **console.log(data)** pra ver o que está chegando, se não estiver chegando nada aí o problema é nesse service!

Comment: Está chegando sim, este observable inclusive uso em todo o APP.. mas o menu não atualiza, uma vez que ele carrega antes do usuário fazer o login.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei um site explicando como esconder / exibir menu baseado no login do usuário.

http://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-hide-navbar-login-page/

o observable está sendo implementado de maneira diferente do que estava usando, fiz outro observable igual ao que mostra no site e funcionou

```
private IsLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

get _IsLoggedIn() {
    return this.IsLoggedIn.asObservable(); 
}
```

após login executado com sucesso, retorna.

```
this.IsLoggedIn.next(true);
```